# Laravel Eloquent filter record on with query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a relationship: `User - Task (BelongsToMany)`.

**Tasks table:**

[image]

**Task_user table:**

[image]

**So, task #11 is assigned to both user #1 and #2**

Then I create a table to log all the processes when a user performs a task. It is called: `appraisals`.

**Appraisals table:**

[image]

When the task is done, the `percent` field is set to `100`

Now, I want to get unfinished tasks of each user. Unfinished task means that task doesn't have any appraisals and the `percent` field is not equal 100.

Here is my code:

```
$unfinishedTasks = User::with(['tasks' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('end_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d')); // Get unexpired tasks
    $query->doesnthave('appraisals'); // Doesn't have any appraisals
    $query->orWhereHas('appraisals', function ($query) {
        $query->where('percent', '!=', 100); // The percent field is not equal 100.
    });
}])->get();


dd($unfinishedTasks->toArray());
```

Here is the result:

[image]

`User #2` only has a `task with id #12`. What I expect is `user #2` should have 2 tasks: `#12 and #11` because `task #11` is assigned to both user `#1 and #2`, only `user #1` has finished the task, `user #2` hasn't.

Comment: I have a concern about using the same `$query` var here `$query`->orWhereHas('appraisals', function (`$query`) {
        $query->where('percent', '!=', 100); // The percent field is not equal 100.
    });

Comment: I'm speculating that using `doesntHave` within the `with` will not necessarily filter the relationship by the user so if any user has an appraisal that's 100% then that task will be excluded for all users.

Comment: Shouldn't you be chaining all those queries together?
where(...)->doesntHave(...)->etc

Comment: Might be more readable to create an `isFinished` attribute on the Task model?

Comment: Can you show the dump of the generated query?

Comment: @mdexp for somehow when I use toSql() query it just printed `"select * from `users`"` :(

Comment: You can try to use this piece of code in any service provider to store in `/storage/logs/query.log` every query made thorugh Laravel: `DB::listen(function($query) {
            File::append(
                storage_path('/logs/query.log'),
                $query->sql . ' ' . json_encode($query->bindings) . PHP_EOL
           );
        });`

Comment: Here is the log file: https://gist.github.com/phuclh/e37c58f6498e9e7d621ee42eb6adae19